# Is the ring $R$ a topological ring with respect to the following topology?

Tags: general-topology, modules, noncommutative-algebra, topological-rings

### **Background**

This question is motivated by trying to answer [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288072/m-systems-and-n-systems-in-topological-rings). But before going into the question straight let me give some background.

> **Definition 1.** Let $R$ be a ring and $A$ be an ideal of $R$. Let $\mathcal{T}_A$ denote the set of all semiprime ideals of $R$ containing $A$. Then, $$\beta(A):=\bigcap_{Q\in \mathcal{T}_A}A$$ called the prime radical of $A$.

Let us now make the following definition,

> **Definition 2.** Let $R$ be a ring and $A\subseteq R$. Let $\mathcal{T}_A$ denote the set of all semiprime ideals of $R$ containing $A$. Then, $$\eta(A):=\bigcap_{Q\in \mathcal{T}_A}A$$ we call $\eta(A)$ to be *the prime radical of $A$ in $R$*.

We now note the following,

> **Theorem 1.** Let $R$ be a ring and $A\subseteq R$. Let $\mathscr{P}(R)$ denote the power set of $R$. Define, $\Phi:\mathscr{P}(R)\to \mathscr{P}(R)$ by, $$\Phi(A)=\eta(A)$$Then,
>
> - $A\subseteq \Phi(A)$ for all $A\in \mathscr{P}(R)$
> - $A\subseteq B\implies \Phi(A)\subseteq \Phi(B)$ for all $A,B\in \mathscr{P}(R)$
> - $\Phi(\Phi(A))=\Phi(A)$ for all $A\in \mathscr{P}(R)$

Each of the properties follows immediately from **Definition 2**. Consequently we claim that the operator $\Phi$ is a closure operator on $R$. So, it generates a topology on $R$. Denote this topological space by $(R,\tau)$ and call this space (for the time being) the **prime radical space of $R$**, the topology being **prime radical topology on $R$**.

### **Question**

> Is $(R,+,\cdot)$ a topological ring with respect to the prime radical topology?

I am interested in this question because if the answer of this question is affirmative then the answer of MO post linked above seems to be affirmative for *at least* for this topology on $R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Question**

> Is $(R,+,\cdot)$ a topological ring with respect to the prime radical topology?

### **Answer**

It is not true that $(R,+,\cdot)$ is *always* a topological ring with respect to the prime radical topology. We don't give any specific counterexample but instead point out a way to construct such a counterexample. The construction of an explicit counterexample is left to the interested reader.

**Theorem 1.** Let $(R,+,\cdot)$ be a ring such that $x^n\ne x$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0,1\}$ and for all non-zero, non-identity $x\in R$. Equip $R$ with prime radical topology. If $(R,+,\cdot)$ is a topological ring with respect to the prime radical topology then the prime radical space of $R$ is Hausdorff.

*Proof.* Since $(R,+,\cdot)$ is a topological ring, it follows that $(R,+)$ is a topological group under the same topology. Since a $T_0$-topological group is Hausdorff, it is enough to show that the prime radical space of $R$ is $T_0$.

For this purpose let $x,y\in R$ such that $x\ne y$. Then consider the $m$-systems $\mathscr{N}(x):=\{x,x^2,\ldots,x^n\}$ and $\mathscr{N}(y):=\{y,y^2,\ldots,y^n\}$. Note that both $\mathscr{N}(x)$ and $\mathscr{N}(y)$ are open.

If either $x=0$ then $\mathscr{N}(y)$ is an open set which contains $y$ but not $0$ and we are done in this case. Similar will be the argument if $y=0$.

So we assume that $x,y\ne 0$. If $y=x^n$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$ then note that $n>1$ and that $y\ne 1$. Now consider $\mathscr{N}(y)$. Notice that $y\in\mathscr{N}(y)$ but $x\notin \mathscr{N}(y)$  by our hypothesis. Otherwise if $x^n\ne y$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ then it follows that $x\in \mathscr{N}(x)$ but $y\notin \mathscr{N}(x)$.

So we are done.

**Theorem 2.** The prime radical space of a nontrivial $R$ is always non-$T_1$.

*Proof.* It is enough to prove that there exist a singleton set in $R$ which is not closed. But this is easy since

- The closed sets of the prime radical space of $R$ are precisely the semiprime ideals of $R$.
- $R$ is nontrivial.
- No singleton subset of $R\setminus\{0\}$ is an ideal of $R$.

So we are done.